# LINQ query with ManagementObjectSearcher in Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, wmi

I have following powershell query which I would like to translate to .net core C#

```
@(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration `
    | Select-Object -Property @{name='IPAddress';Expression={($_.IPAddress[0])}},MacAddress,Description `
    | Where IPAddress -NE $null)
```

This selects all ip4 addresses plus MacAddress and Description.

But already just picking the ip4 addresses seems to be harder. So far I have this:

```
    var rx = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
    var testregex = rx.IsMatch("192.168.11.2");
ManagementObjectSearcher NetworkSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT IPAddress,MacAddress,Description FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'");
    var sIPAddress =
        NetworkSearcher.Get()
        .Cast<ManagementObject>()
        .Where((o) => rx.IsMatch((string)o["IPAddress"]));
    //.SelectMany(o => (string[])(o["IPAddress"])));

    var sIPAddress2 =
        NetworkSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().SelectMany(mo => mo.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>())
        .Where(pd => pd.Name == "IPAddress" && (t => rx.IsMatch(t)); ;
```

I guess one of my problems is that the attribute names are unknown, but also removing the not ipv4 addresses. I am using WMI because later I also need to query the MSFT_NetIPAddress class.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code that way:

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher NetworkSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT IPAddress,MacAddress,Description FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'");

    var rx = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");

    foreach (ManagementObject prop in NetworkSearcher.Get())
    {
        if (rx.IsMatch(((String[])prop["IPAddress"])[0])) { 
            ipaddress.Add(String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t\t{2}", ((String[])prop["IPAddress"])[0], prop["MacAddress"], prop["Description"] ));
        }
    }
```

Not exactly the solution I was looking for but its ok for now

Comment: Have tried using ORMi library? https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi